# GDB initialize array with contents

Tags: arrays, c, memory, initialization, gdb

I've not found what I am looking for, so I'll formulate my own question.

Consider the C-program below

```
char heap[<some-static-size>];

void main() {
  <this-code-reads-and-writes-to-heap>
}
```

I would like to execute this program in `gdb`, after first having initialized `heap`. One posibility is that i put the contents of the array in a file, and somehow feed that to gdb. How could I do this easiest? Once `main` is done, I would like to read the contents of `heap` and write it to some other file.

Comment: Are you not putting the initial data in the source code because it changes frequently? How frequently? If you are going to read the data from a file, will it be in binary form or a form like C source code? (E.g., raw bytes or text like `0x37, 0xfe,…`?) Why not put some lines at the start of `main` to read the data? A simple loop with `scanf` could read the data. If you need to use `gdb`, you could write the file in the form of gdb commands that assign values to locations in the array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It will change frequently, yes. This is part of a larger project concerning compiler testing. The data for the array will be spit out by the test harness, so I can output either format. It is under my control. I would like to keep this initialization code out of the generated program itself, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GDB [dump and restore](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html) commands can be used here. Set breakpoints at `main` and `exit`. Use `&heap[0]` as the start address.

```c
$ cat heap.c
char heap[100];

int main() {
    heap[0]++;
}
```

```
$ dd if=/dev/random of=input.bin count=1 ibs=100
1+0 records in
0+1 records out
100 bytes copied, 0.000306025 s, 327 kB/s
```

```
$ gdb -q heap
(gdb) b main
(gdb) commands
>restore input.bin binary &heap[0]
>continue
>end
(gdb) b exit
(gdb) commands
>dump binary memory output.bin &heap[0] &heap[100]
>continue
>end
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1, main () at heap.c:4
4       heap[0]++;
Restoring binary file input.bin into memory (0x555555558040 to 0x5555555580a4)
Breakpoint 2, __GI__exit (status=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/_exit.c:140
[Inferior 1 (process 9802) exited normally]
(gdb) q
```

```
$ cmp -l input.bin output.bin
  1  52  53
```

Comment: This is precisely what I want to do. It works, apart from me gdb giving me an error when I set the breakpoint `_Exit`. It says "function _Exit not defined". I am sure that I can find some other workaround for finding the end of my function though.

Comment: I misremembered the C standard. Returning from `main` is equivalent to calling `exit`, not `_Exit`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried for a while to search for solutions to this, but no form of `_Exit` or `exit` works for me, I get the same error. My `main` always appear at the end, and I can infer a suitable breakpoint by inspecting the number of lines in the file, so for my purposes this is not a problem. It would, however, be a better solution if I could manage to set the proper breakpoint.

Comment: Would it be posible to add a call to `exit(0);` at the end of your `main` and at any point in `main` that does a `return`?

Comment: main never returns prematurely, but I can absolutely add a call to `exit(0)` at the end :) That should solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a shared library that does:

1. In a constructor, based on environment variable `HEAPFILE`, does `mmap` so `heap` is R/W mapped to `HEAPFILE` (Note: trickery involved, see code below)
2. Target program will have `heap` setup [magically ;-)].
3. When target program completes, shared library destructor will copy contents of [possibly modified] `heap` to the file `HEAPOUT`

Of course, these filenames *could* be program arguments and the target program *could* call the constructor and destructor functions explictly but you wanted the target program to be [largely] unaware of what data it's been given.

You can have *many* different target programs (i.e. programs that you want to "inject" data into). They only need to be compiled and linked *once* but many different data files can be used.

So, you can easily do: Test N programs with M data inputs.

---

Here is the shared library code. Note that although it has *some* error checking, and it *works*, it could be cleaned up a bit.

```
// libtst.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

// exported to target program
char *heap;                             // pointer to heap
size_t heapsize;                        // bytes in heap

// private
static char *heap_file;                 // input file
static char *heap_ofile;                // output file
static int heap_fd;                     // open file descriptor for heap_file
static struct stat heap_st;             // result of stat for heap_file

void __attribute__((constructor))
fakeinit(void)
{

    do {
        // get input file name
        heap_file = getenv("HEAPFILE");
        if (heap_file == NULL)
            break;

        // get output file name
        heap_ofile = getenv("HEAPOUT");
        if (heap_ofile == NULL)
            break;

        // open input file
        heap_fd = open(heap_file,O_RDONLY);
        if (heap_fd < 0)
            break;

        // get input file size (and export this for target program)
        if (fstat(heap_fd,&heap_st) < 0)
            break;
        heapsize = heap_st.st_size;

        // map this for the target program
        // NOTE: by using PROT_READ/PROT_WRITE target program will think this
        // is an ordinary array, but MAP_PRIVATE will prevent original file
        // from being altered
        heap = mmap(NULL,heapsize,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_PRIVATE,
            heap_fd,0);

        if (heap == MAP_FAILED) {
            dbgprt("fakeinit: FAILED\n");
            heap = NULL;
            break;
        }
    } while (0);
}

void __attribute__((destructor))
fakefini(void)
{

    do {
        // open the output file
        int fdout = open(heap_ofile,O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0644);
        if (fdout < 0)
            break;

        // enlarge output file to correct size
        dbgprt("fakefini: heapsize=%zu\n",heapsize);
        ftruncate(fdout,heapsize);

        // map the output file R/W
        char *outbuf = mmap(NULL,heapsize,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED,
            fdout,0);
        if (outbuf == MAP_FAILED) {
            dbgprt("fakefini: FAILED\n");
            break;
        }

        // put data into output file
        memcpy(outbuf,heap,heapsize);

        // unmap/close output file
        munmap(outbuf,heapsize);
        close(fdout);

        // unmap/close input file
        munmap(heap,heapsize);
        close(heap_fd);
    } while (0);
}
```

---

Here is the sample program to run under test:

```
// test.c -- sample program to be run under test
#include <stddef.h>

// set by shared library
extern char *heap;
extern size_t heapsize;

int
main(void)
{

    heap[0] += 1;
    heap[1] += 1;
    heap[2] += 1;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is a build/run script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cc -o libtst.so -shared -fpic libtst.c -g -DDEBUG=1
cc -o test test.c ./libtst.so -g

echo "abc" > old
rm -f new

env HEAPFILE=old HEAPOUT=new ./test

head -1000 old new
```

---

Here is the output of `sh -x ./build`:

```
+ cc -o libtst.so -shared -fpic libtst.c -g -DDEBUG=1
+ cc -o test test.c ./libtst.so -g
+ echo abc
+ rm -f new
+ env HEAPFILE=old HEAPOUT=new ./test
fakefini: heapsize=4
+ head -1000 old new
==> old <==
abc

==> new <==
bcd
```

---

Note that above *links* the program against the shared test library.

This is the easiest. But, it occurs to me, that you'd like the target program to be totally unaware of how `heap` is initialized.

Although I didn't try it, it *should* be possible [with some slight modifications (e.g.) using ELF weak symbols/aliases] to change `libtst.so` so that it *force* itself on the target programs using:

```
env LD_PRELOAD=./libtst.so ./test
```

Comment: This is a nice hack, but you are correct in that I don't want my target program to make any assumptions of how heap is initialized. I am sure your answer is helpful to someone without this requirement, however. Thank you!